# QPython prompts "Press enter to exit" after running script. How to interact with console instead?

Tags: qpython3

When I run any script in QPython, it runs in a console then I get prompted "Press enter to exit", but I want to interact with my just-run script instead of exiting. Is there any configuration option to control this behavior?

Does it have anything to do with the <&& exit> option displayed at the top of the console?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

Import os
os.system("sh")

Comment: When I try that, I don't see the results of my script. For example, if my script is: import os os.system("sh") test = 2; print(test) I just get a shell prompt $. If I remove the os.system call, I get the value 2 printed, before #[QPython] Press enter to exit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the console, you could try to raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to the default import path and than import it from the interactive shell

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts')
sys.path.append('/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects')
```

when you are using qpython3 change it to projects3/scripts3.

than do:

```
import MyScript
```

or

```
from MyScript import MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old post, but I had the same problem:

You need to switch your keyboard to word based instead of character based.
(Enter the three points- preferences-input method-word based) Then you receive a keyboard with an enter-sign.

Press enter and it exits.